How to test constructability without false-positives or false-negatives?
I'm trying to see if an object of type T can be constructed with an argument of type U.
You'd think std::is_constructible would be close enough (aside from the fact that it also checks destructability, which I would've ideally liked to avoid), but apparently this fails:
#include <type_traits>
using U = int;
enum T : U { };
static_assert(std::is_constructible<T, U>::value, "error");  // fails
static_assert(std::is_convertible<U, T>::value, "error");  // fails

I guess that makes sense, since T e((U())) fails, but that's not what I'm looking for because auto v = T(U()) and auto v = static_cast<T>(U()) both succeed.
This also makes me wonder what other edge cases I may have missed... I have no idea.
What's the right way to test solely constructability via the T(...) syntax, ideally using standard traits, with as few false-positives or false-negatives as possible?

T(U()) is function-style cast (equivalent to C-style cast and is considered bad for many reasons). Maybe you need to define in a clearer way what kind of constructibility you are looking for.

template <typename T, typename... Ts> concept is_constructible =  requires(Ts...args) { T(args...);};? Demo.

The thing is that, std::is_convertible<U, T>::value is true. I don't know why you think it got false.

All major three report false, https://godbolt.org/z/cE6fTKxnr.

@ALX23z Its false in my tests: https://godbolt.org/z/9oqoE6saW

@NathanOliver oh, my bad. I've tested it in reverse order by renaming constructible to convertible. Hmm...

It is intresting that T e((U())) fails to compile but T e{U()} compiles just fine.  Oh the joys of C++ initialization.

@NathanOliver was testing OnlineGDB and T e{U()} fails to compile in C++14 but succeeds in C++17 and up.

Even more joy than before ;)

@NathanOliver cppreference seems to have a section devoted to it.

@WeijunZhou: for the purposes of this question I literally only care about the T(...) syntax, not how good or bad the practice is. Also note that the equivalence to C-style casts is only true for 1-arg, but I'm asking I general.

If that is the case, the method by Jarod42 is the way to go.

@WeijunZhou: that one tests destructability too, so it would have false negatives.

What I find bizarre is that template<class T, class... U> concept is_constructible = requires(void *p) { ::new(p) T(T(std::declval<U>()...)); }; doesn't work. The destructor isn't even called here; why is it required to be accessible?

Assuming no elision, then the destructor is called for the temporary T. Remove the extra T then it works. https://godbolt.org/z/zoecxc1eM

@WeijunZhou: "Assuming no elision" -- elision is mandatory here so I don't see how you can assume that. And if I remove the extra T then it won't work for e.g. the enum example.
